# How to create and apply Spring Animation to a UWP control?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I intend to add a horizontal displacement with oscillating effect on a grid (LoginBody) upon loaded. After researching I think Spring Animation is the right thing to use. The code I derived from MS's tutorial so far is obviously not valid. For starter I'm not familiar with adding a CompositionObject into the visual tree. Also I'm not sure how to set "Offset.X" as the target property. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
  private void LoginBody_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Compositor _compositor = new Compositor();
        SpringScalarNaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation =_compositor.CreateSpringScalarAnimation();
        _springAnimation.DampingRatio = 0.75f;
        _springAnimation.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        _springAnimation.InitialValueExpressions["FinalValue"] = "this.StartingValue + 250";

        LoginBody.StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't instantiate a new Compositor, it's a global object you simply want to reference. The easiest way:

```
Compositor _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
```

You don't mention what 'LoginBody' is or where it came from. If it is a UIElement that has been added to a XAML file, then it is already part of the Visual Tree. Or, if 'LoginBody'  is type Visual that you obtained by using:

```
Visual LoginBody = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementChildVisual(myUIElement);
```

That too is already part of the Visual Tree (assuming myUIElement is). However if 'LoginBody' is a newly created SpriteVisual or ContainerVisual, for example, then you have to add it to the Visual Tree like so:

```
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(myGrid, LoginBody);
```

My guess is that just fixing your Compositor reference will put you on the right path.

Comment: Ok thank you. LoginBody is already in xaml file. Any idea regarding how to set Offset.X as the property to animate?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I used loginBody.StartAnimation("Offset.X",_springAnimation); where loginBody is a visual fetched from the UIElement LoginBody